# How would I make a tableview lead to a page which had another tableview?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, tableview

I want to make a tableview; when you press a cell it takes you to another tableview. If you press a cell on the second table, it takes you to another view. Then, you could go back if you want or whatever. How would I do this? I can make a tableview lead to a new view already, but the real question is how to make another tableview and lead to another view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if I follow..

Anyhow, I recommend you create a UINavigationController and set the rootViewController to your tableView's controller view property, when a cell is tapped in your tableview you should implement:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

where you would create an instance of another view controller that holds your desired "different" tableview obviously and push it to the navigation controller.

I recommend you take a look at the view controllers programming guide as well as tableviews. It isn't that complex.

The key idea is to know that this behavior you want is basically how the navigation controller works by pushing and popping views.

If you implement it this way (which is what you should be doing) you get lots of functionality for free, such as the behavior when tapping on the "back" button.

Hope it helps.

Comment: No problem, do a search on the web with pushing and popping views with the navigation controller. There are probably many code examples out there showing what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to use both tables in the same view controller or do you want to use navigation controller to navigate to the next table view?  If you want to use both the tables in the same view controller then differentiate them by tag value.